# Flutter sliding container into another container to show or hide some icons like with toolbar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

in container you suppose i have `AppBar()` witch that i want to have another invisible container, like with this screen shot:

[image]

in that two other container are invisible and i want to show them by sliding from top to bottom or bottom to top for change visibility on visible or invisible

**sliding from top to bottom to show or sliding that to top to hide**

[image]

**sliding from bottom to top to show or sliding that to bottom to hide**

[image]

is any library to implementing this sliding animation?

Comment: You can do this easily using a gesture detector, "onVerticalDragEnd" callback you can use a bool to display the container...

Comment: @VidorVistrom i can't find any sample code to implementing that

Comment: Of course, you won't get the exact sample code for this. I could suggest you the following: Row-->[ (GestureDetector-->Container), AppBar,  (GestureDetector-->Container)]

Comment: @CopsOnRoad could you help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: Image goes here]

---

Click on arrows to bring the top/bottom containers, and after that to hide those new containers, you can either drag them up/down or simply touch them.

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: HomePage()));

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  static double _height = 100, _one = -_height, _two = _height;
  final double _oneFixed = -_height;
  final double _twoFixed = _height;
  Duration _duration = Duration(milliseconds: 5);
  bool _top = false, _bottom = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Slide")),
      body: SizedBox(
        height: _height,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              height: _height,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onVerticalDragEnd: (details) {
                  if (details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dy >= 0) _toggleTop();
                  else _toggleBottom();
                },
                child: _myContainer(
                  color: Colors.yellow[800],
                  text: "Old Container",
                  child1: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
                    onPressed: _toggleTop,
                  ),
                  child2: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_upward),
                    onPressed: _toggleBottom,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              top: _one,
              height: _height,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: _toggleTop,
                onPanEnd: (details) => _toggleTop(),
                onPanUpdate: (details) {
                  _one += details.delta.dy;
                  if (_one >= 0) _one = 0;
                  if (_one <= _oneFixed) _one = _oneFixed;
                  setState(() {});
                },
                child: _myContainer(
                  color: _one >= _oneFixed + 1 ? Colors.red[800] : Colors.transparent,
                  text: "Upper Container",
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              top: _two,
              height: _height,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: _toggleBottom,
                onPanEnd: (details) => _toggleBottom(),
                onPanUpdate: (details) {
                  _two += details.delta.dy;
                  if (_two <= 0) _two = 0;
                  if (_two >= _twoFixed) _two = _twoFixed;
                  setState(() {});
                },
                child: _myContainer(
                  color: _two <= _twoFixed - 1 ? Colors.green[800] : Colors.transparent,
                  text: "Bottom Container",
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _toggleTop() {
    _top = !_top;
    Timer.periodic(_duration, (timer) {
      if (_top) _one += 2;
      else _one -= 2;

      if (_one >= 0) {
        _one = 0;
        timer.cancel();
      }
      if (_one <= _oneFixed) {
        _one = _oneFixed;
        timer.cancel();
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  void _toggleBottom() {
    _bottom = !_bottom;
    Timer.periodic(_duration, (timer) {
      if (_bottom) _two -= 2;
      else _two += 2;

      if (_two <= 0) {
        _two = 0;
        timer.cancel();
      }
      if (_two >= _twoFixed) {
        _two = _twoFixed;
        timer.cancel();
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  Widget _myContainer({Color color, String text, Widget child1, Widget child2, Function onTap}) {
    Widget child;
    if (child1 == null || child2 == null) {
      child = Text(text, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold));
    } else {
      child = Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          child1,
          child2,
        ],
      );
    }
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Container(
        color: color,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Output:**

[image]

---

If I got you correctly, this is the solution.

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: HomePage()));

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  static double _height = 100, _offset = 10, _one = -(_height - _offset), _two = (_height - _offset);
  final double _oneFixed = -(_height - _offset);
  final double _twoFixed = (_height - _offset);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Testing")),
      body: SizedBox(
        height: _height,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              height: _height,
              child: _myContainer(color: Colors.grey[800], text: "Old Container"),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              top: _one,
              height: _height,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onPanUpdate: (details) {
                  _one += details.delta.dy;
                  if (_one >= 0) _one = 0;
                  if (_one <= _oneFixed) _one = _oneFixed;
                  setState(() {});
                },
                child: _myContainer(color: _one >= _oneFixed + 1 ? Colors.red[800] : Colors.transparent, text: "Upper Container"),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              top: _two,
              height: _height,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onPanUpdate: (details) {
                  _two += details.delta.dy;
                  if (_two <= 0) _two = 0;
                  if (_two >= _twoFixed) _two = _twoFixed;
                  setState(() {});
                },
                child: _myContainer(color: _two <= _twoFixed - 1 ? Colors.green[800] : Colors.transparent, text: "Bottom Container"),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _myContainer({Color color, String text}) {
    return Container(
      color: color,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Text(text, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
    );
  }
}
```