# Is there a widget to implement a welcome screen?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to implement a "welcome screen" which is shown every time the app is opened. So it's no common welcome screen in the sense of an "app introduction screen".
The welcome screen should be swiped to the top, to "enter" the app on the main page. Therefore I want this Widget to be on top of the main page, maybe in a stack-widget, so the main page is partly visible while the welcome page is swiped to the top. After that, the welcome screen shouldn't be visible anymore.
So my question is if there's a widget, which offers these possibilities.

My approaches were as follows:

I've already tried a PageView, but this doesn't support the overlay (stack) of both screens.

A "sliding Container" as suggested in the answers [on this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57149002/flutter-sliding-container-into-another-container-to-show-or-hide-some-icons-like)
But I wasn't able to "transform" the containers to the requirements described above.

Some other ideas were to use the [flutter swiper](https://github.com/best-flutter/flutter_swiper) but I think the adaption would be too difficult.

Therefore I hope to get some suggestions which libs I could use to implement this.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably better ways to do it but...

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget welcome = WelcomeView();
  final Widget home = HomeView();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned.fill(child: home),
            Positioned(bottom: 100, child: welcome),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          'HomeView',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class WelcomeView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dismissible(
      key: UniqueKey(),
      direction: DismissDirection.up,
      child: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Welcome!!!',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works for me in generell, but when I navigate from another screen back to the `HomeView` the screen suddenly turns transparent red and the buttons on the home page aren't clickable anymore. Is this due to the `Dismissible`?

Comment: Yes, when you navigate away and then back to MyHomePage, the entire Stack is rebuilt.  To handle this you need state management on MyHomePage.  If first run, display welcome else do not display welcome.  To do this requires converting MyHomePage to a StatefullWidget or some other possibly more complex state management solution.  Keep plugging away.  This is very doable.